# Android In-app billing, How to determine whether to call consumeAsync or acknowledgePurchase?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I have implemented the Android in-app billing library version 5.0.0, there are multiple subscription products and in-app(consumable) products shown on the same screen for the user to purchase in my app.

The onPurchasesUpdated listener is called after the purchase is completed by the user, but the `List<Purchase>` provided by this listener doesn't contain `BillingClient.ProductType` bit in any of the products, so how do we decide to call `BillingClient.consumeAsync` or `BillingClient.acknowledgePurchase` method?